# Subsets of dense set

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be complete  linear metric space. Is it true that if we remove from a dense subset $A$ of $X$ a subset which has cardinality less then cardinality of $A$ then we obtain dense subset of $X$ ? If not, what about Banach spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Consider $X=\mathbb R$ and $A=\mathbb Q\cup [0,1]$, and remove from $A$ the subset $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Sorry about my previous comment. I interpreted the question this way, which makes more sense to me (and should be true, at least for Banach spaces): Suppose $X$ is a complete linear metric space and $\kappa$ is the smallest cardinality of a dense set $D$ (the density character). Is it true that removing $\lambda \lt \kappa$ elements from a dense set $D$ still leaves us with a dense set? This [answer from Bill Johnson on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/72750/density-character-and-cardinality/72824#72824) is somewhat related and interesting.

Comment: @Theo: I was thinking about the same thing. I figured read again the question and then I saw that Jonas made sense :-)

Comment: Theo: Thanks for clarifying.  That sounds true to me, too, because a set with cardinality $\lambda$ would be nowhere dense.

Comment: Right, that's it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. How to see that if $A$ has the smallest cardinality κ then set with cardinality  λ<κ will be nowhere dense?

Comment: @col: Suppose $B$ has cardinality $\lambda$ and $B$ is *not* nowhere dense (and we can assume $\lambda$ is infinite).  Then $\overline B$ contains some open subset $U$ of $X$.  If $x$ is in $U$, then $X=\cup_{n=1}^\infty n(U-x)$, so $\cup_{n=1}^\infty n(B-x)$ is dense in $X$ and has cardinality $\lambda$.